# Inserting Json objects in PostgreSQL json fields with Anorm

Tags: json, scala, types, playframework, anorm

How can I pass a `JsObject` into a `json` data type field in a PostgreSQL 9.3 database with Anorm without having to cast it as a string?

Given a PostgreSQL 9.3 table such as:

```
create table profiles
(
  id serial primary key,
  profile json null
);
```

With Play 2.2, this test succeeds:

```
package helpers

import anorm._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.test._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class AnormTest extends Specification {
  "AnormTest" should {
    "insert a JSON object" in new WithApplication {
      val profile = Json.obj("language" -> "en")
      val sql = SQL("insert into profiles (profile) values (CAST({profile} AS json))")
        .on("profile" -> profile.toString)
      DB.withConnection { implicit c => sql.execute() }
    }
  }
}
```

But with these lines changed:

```
      val sql = SQL("insert into profiles (profile) values ({profile})")
        .on("profile" -> profile)
```

It produces this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsObject. 
Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Since with Anorm we usually pass the appropriate data types instead of text (for instance, an `UUID` object for a column of `uuid` data type), it's not optimal having to convert the `JsObject` to a string and cast it back to the `json` data type in the SQL statement.

For an example of this issue and its workaround, please refer to [Using PostgreSQL's native JSON support in Play Framework 2.1-RC1](http://www.philmateleven.com/2013/01/using-postgresqls-native-json-support.html).

How can this be avoided with Anorm in order to pass the `JsObject` directly as a `json` data type?

Answer (score 8):

For the Play 2.4 and above use the anorm.Object(value: org.postgresql.util.PGobject) class instead of value directly:

```
val pgObject = new org.postgresql.util.PGobject();
pgObject.setType("json");
pgObject.setValue(profile);
val sql = SQL("insert into profiles (profile) values ({profile})")
    .on("profile" -> anorm.Object(pgObject))
```